# most effective & easiest solution for expression evaluation c++

Tags: c++, pointers, expression, evaluation

many programs needs to evaluate expressions like:

input: (T(TF)) ---> output: false (T as true, and F as false)

OR

input (a (b c 2) 3)$ ---> output: abcbcabcbcabcbc

in other words,how to deal with expressions that contain braces?

I used to push to stack until I reach ')'.
then, pop until I reach '(', and so on.
but that would take a long execution time and missy code!

and if I tried to take good of @Henrik code to solve arithmetic expression, I end up with a wrong answer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const char * expressionToParse = "(T(TT))";
char peek()
{
    return *expressionToParse;
}

char get()
{
    return *expressionToParse++;
}
bool expression();
bool number()
{
    bool result = get() - '0';
//even if I remove -'0'
    cout<<"number() result:"<<result<<endl;
    while (peek() == 'T' || peek() == 'F')
    {
        if (peek()=='T' && get()=='T') {
            result=true;
        }
        else{
            result=false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
bool factor()
{
    if (peek() == 'T' && peek() <= 'F')
        return number();
    else if (peek() == '(')
    {
        get(); // '('
        bool result = expression();
        get(); // ')'
        return result;
    }
    return 0; // error
}


bool expression()
{
    bool result = factor();
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    bool result = expression();
    if(result){
        cout<<"true";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"false";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use a library, e.g. boost spirit : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Thank you,I will search for it to get the idea,but is it working on c++ 3.4.2?

Comment: hmm, on reflection maybe it's not the best thing to recommend...it's not the easiest thing to get started using